# Passing URL parameters to a ClickOnce application in any browser

Tags: .net, url, deployment, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application, and I need the ability to pass URL parameters to it. For example, a user could click a URL of the form "http://foo.bar/MyApp.application?flavor=grape", and this will launch my application, passing the "?flavor=grape" query to it.

Unfortunately, it looks like this only works in IE out of the box. On Firefox and Chrome, the user must install add-ons in order to get ClickOnce deployment to work. My users work in a restrictive corporate environment, and are not allowed to install any add-ons, or anything else for that matter (ClickOnce does work for them, though). So, what do I do ?

One hack I could think of is registering my application as a file handler for some sufficiently unique file extension, such as ".bugmaster" . Then -- or so my theory went -- I could have my webserver generate a file named "flavor_grape.bugmaster"; the user will click a URL pointing to that file, then choose "Run" instead of "Save", and this will launch my application, who will then parse the filename for URL parameters. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work either. It works perfectly fine when the "flavor_grape.bugmaster" file is opened from the local filesystem, but, for some reason, this does not work when the user attempts to open the file from a browser.

Does anyone have any other ideas ?

Answer (score 12):

There's a nifty little trick to ClickOnce in that you can actually encode parameters directly into the URL that gets used by setup.exe. So for example, to create a setup.exe that contains your 'flavor=grape' parameter, you could run the following from the command line:

```
copy setup.exe setup-for-grape.exe
setup.exe -url="http://foo.bar/MyApp.application?flavor=grape" /dest=setup-for-grape.exe
```

This uses the undocumented /dest flag to output the results to the setup-for-grape.exe file, instead of modifying the original setup.exe. After doing this, setup-for-grape.exe will point to your URL *and* will contain your flavor=grape parameter. Note that if you are using signing, you'll need to do this to an *un-signed* copy of your setup.exe, and then sign it afterwards, as it breaks the signature.

If the number of possible parameter choices is fairly limited, you can just generate setup.exe's for them all and link to them from your website.

On the other hand, if there are an unlimited number of choices, you can set up a web service which takes in some parameters, generates a setup.exe with desired parameters encoded in it, and spits it back out to the client. I have used this method to generate setup.exe's for clients connected to specific servers - the client installation URLs have the server connection info encoded in them, so when a client is installed it automatically knows what server to connect to.

Of course, if you don't want to use setup.exe, or if your restrictive corporate environment disallows it, all of this goes straight out the window. But hopefully you'll find it useful, or at least informative.

Comment: Wow! You learn new things every day.  I've been working with ClickOnce for a while, and I've somehow missed this option.  @Marty Dill: Have you used this technique in the past?

Comment: Yup! See my second last paragraph. I used it to generate setup.exe's that contain information on what server to connect to. Once the system was all up and running it worked quite nicely.

Comment: This is a neat trick indeed, but unfrotunately I do need an unlimited number of options (well, I guess technically it's limited, but there are more than 1e10 of them), and my application does need to be signed. Although I could probably set up the web service to sign the app, as well. It's an interesting idea, though, thanks !

Comment: Yup, you can definitely get the web service to do the signing. I can't remember the command off the top of my head, but it's pretty easy.

Comment: Hi Marty, I also found myself in need of passing a parameter to my ClickOnce application. The application would also have to be run by a scheduled task. Your solution looks ideal, but I'm not sure about the signing. You say that "if you are using signing, you'll need to do this to an un-signed copy of your setup.exe, and then sign it afterwards, as it breaks the signature". Must I sign setup.exe or setup-for-grape.exe, and when must I sign it? When I publish out of Visual Studio, it switches on the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" option automatically, so how do I get an unsigned copy?

Comment: You need to sign setup-for-grape.exe after generating it from your unsigned setup.exe. You should be able to get an unsigned copy of setup.exe by publishing with 'Sign the ClickOnce manifests' checked, and then unchecking it and publishing again. It seems that Visual Studio always checks it the first time you publish, but you can turn it off for subsequent publishes (I just tested this).

Comment: I know this answer is fairly old, but when I try this technique, the bootstrapper ends up with the url `http://foo.bar/MyApp.application?flavor=grape/MyApp.application` instead of `http://foo.bar/MyApp.application?flavor=grape`. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @MartyDill may I ask, how did you find this undocumented /dest flag, I cant find any reference to it anywhere

Comment: I wonder what exactly is the point of the `/dest` flag..  It seems to need the target file anyhow so you need the pre-`COPY`.  But if you copied it, you can just `setup-for-grape.exe -url=...` to change its url.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer probably worked in the past, but using that undocumented `/dest` parameter now just fails with: *Unable to modify 'grape_setup.exe'.  The file may be read-only or locked.*

Fortunately, `/dest` wasn't necessary when I tried it in VS 2017, and now in VS 2019, so the option can be simply ignored.

### Steps for setting URL:

1. Make a copy of the executable because the next command alters the file:

   ```
    COPY setup.exe grape_setup.exe
   ```
2. Replace the URL like so:

   ```
    grape_setup.exe -url="http://foo.bar/MyApp.application?flavor=grape#"
   ```

This alters `grape_setup.exe` so that subsequent runs launch the ClickOnce application as if it were opened from the specified URL.

But wait, what's that `#` on the end?

For some reason I still haven't figured out, using `-url` gives me an executable that has an extra `/MyApp.application` on the end of the URL.  The `#` is there to separate out this string so it doesn't get treated as part of the last URL param's value.  Using `#` puts it in the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) but alternatives are using `&junk=` or `&_=` or just `&`.

### Resigning the executable

Using `-url` modifies the executable and any Authenticode signatures are removed.

Unfortunately, it removes it in a way that breaks `signtool.exe` when trying to resign:

```
SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x800700C1
        %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

[This blog post](https://markcz.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/signtool-exe-returned-error-0x800700c1/) as well as a [tool called *`delcert`*](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=2508061#post2508061) sheds light on why this is happening.

Here's the output of `delcert`:

```
ImageRemoveCertificate failed with error 0x00000057
This happens when there's a listing in IMAGE_DIRECTORY_SECURITY
in the PE's header, but the actual Authenticode signature has been stripped.
Let's fix that ...
Setting both fields to zero ...
Succeeded.
```

This suggests `-url` removes the signature in a non-clean manner, and `delcert` can fix this for us.

Given of this problem, there appears to be three options for getting a signed executable with embedded URL parameters:

- Uncheck "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" before publishing, publish, then use `-url` to set the URL.  Finally use `signtool.exe` to sign.
- Publish as usual, use `-url` to set the URL.  Follow up with `delcert` to clean the broken signature.  Finally use `signtool.exe` to sign.
- Publish as usual.  Then use `delcert` to remove the signature.  Use `-url` to set the URL, and finally sign with `signtool.exe`.

The three methods all probably create the same executable.  The first requires a change to `.csproj`.  The second and third depend on a third-party software [*`delcert`*](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=2508061#post2508061).

Here's an actual example:

1. Make a copy of the executable as `grape_setup.exe`. (Described in first example)
2. Remove the Authenticode signature:

   ```
   delcert.exe grape_setup.exe
   ```
3. Replace the URL to set our parameters. (Described in first example)
4. Resign the newly created executable:

   ```
   signtool.exe sign /sha1 XYZ /t "http://..." grape_setup.exe
   ```

The value of `/sha1` is `<ManifestCertificateThumbprint>` in the project `.csproj` file.

The value of `/t` is `<ManifestTimestampUrl>` but `/t` can be omitted if timestamping is not required.

### Having the build process leave an unsigned bootstrapper

I found another way of getting an unsigned `setup.exe` which alleviates me having to remove the signature with software like `delcert`.

By adding this to my `.csproj` file, the build process leaves an unsigned copy under `bin\Release\app.publish\` as `unsigned_setup.exe`.

```
<Target Name="UnsignedBootstrapper" AfterTargets="_DeploymentGenerateBootstrapper" BeforeTargets="_DeploymentSignClickOnceDeployment">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(PublishDir)\setup.exe" DestinationFiles="$(PublishDir)\unsigned_setup.exe" />
</Target>
```

The `_DeploymentGenerateBootstrapper` target generates the bootstrapper and `_DeploymentSignClickOnceDeployment` signs it.  The above target runs between the two to make a copy of the executable.

This worked in VS 2019 but target names could differ in other versions.  I came across them by looking at the build output after setting verbosity to "Diagnostic" under `Options` > `Project and Solutions` > `Build and Run`.